# Настройка ReSharper

Tags: configuration, resharper

Привет !

Появился такой вопрос: есть ли какой нибудь рациональный способ установки одних и тех же **конфигураций/настроек** в `ReSharper` на **несколько компьютеров** ?

Допустим у меня есть 300 компьютеров и файл с конфигурацией.
Как я могу быстрым способом залить эту конфигурацию на все компьютеры ?

Может этот вопрос уже где то поднимался и есть хорошее решение =)

Надеюсь вопрос понятен ! 
Спасибо !

UPD.:
Нашел вот [такое](https://habrahabr.ru/post/262383/) решение. Но тут используется NuGet.
Мне бы хотелось хранить настройки в репозитории.

Comment: Первая ссылка из гугла https://habrahabr.ru/post/262383/

Comment: Эту же ссылку я добавил в вопрос.